# Как сделать поиск на laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть товары, у товаров есть характеристики, характеристики хранятся в таблице товаров в столбике `fields` тип - JSON ("id характеристики":"Значение характеристики")

```
 id |   title   | fields
  1 |  Товар 1  | {"1":"Стена"}
  2 |  Товар 2  | {"1":"Стена бетонная"}
  3 |  Товар 3  | {"1":"Стена бетонная окрашенная"}
```

Например когда мы ищем:

1. По характеристике `Стена` - получаем в ответ все товары
2. По характеристике `Стена бетонная` - получаем в ответ товары с `id`: `2, 3`
3. По характеристике `Стена бетонная окрашенная` - получаем в ответ товары с `id`: `3`

Надеюсь объяснил нормально)

У меня в голове 0, в какую сторону идти, что прочитать?

Comment: Например идти в сторону документации... `->where('fields->1', 'Стена')` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses

Comment: Спасибо, такая конструкция и использовалась, только она не отдавала нужный мне результат, решил проблему использованием `LIKE` - `->where("fields->id", 'LIKE', "%value%") и сортировочка ->orderBy("fields->id", 'ASC')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если по простому,то Model::query() ->where('fields', 'LIKE', "%{$searchTerm}%") ->get();
или whereRaw('json_contains(destinations, '["' . $keyword . '"]')')->get()
Если по нормальному - то потрать время и найди крутой  "велосипед". Например https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scout или похожее

Comment: Спасибо, решил проблему использованием `LIKE` - `->where("fields->id", 'LIKE', "%value%") и сортировочка ->orderBy("fields->id", 'ASC')`